Probability of a winning hand in Texas hold'em poker
Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm new to probability and I have a question. Essentially say pre flop you receive an ace and a king. Convention says that it is a toss up roughly 50-50 that you win. However this doesn't seem right to me. Conditional probability tells me that, first you need to calculate the odds of getting an ace and a king. Then you calculate the probability of winning given that you have an ace and a king which is 50%. The product gives you both events simultaneously, probability of winning and probability that hand is an ace and a king. What am I missing here?

The conditional probability doesn't concern itself with the probability of the conditioning event.  Here, we assume that we have an Ace, King.  Doesn't make any difference how probable that is, we start from that premise.

If you're dealt an ace and a king there is a 100% chance that you have an ace and a king.

You mean an Ace or a King somewhere in the 5 community cards (i.e. flop + turn + river).  You normally do not need an Ace and a King.  The (small) probability of losing, even though you did get an Ace or a King is approximately compensated by the small percentage of the time that you win with Ace-King, without improvement.

Okay understood. So what would the product of the probabilities represent. Does it mean anything in the context of poker, to multiply the win rate of the hand with the probability of receiving it?
